# Use Format DE_DE and infinite decimal places in SQL query results

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table on which I query logistics costs. 
The `sqlfiddle` with the table you can find [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/28c574/2):

According to the fiddle, the table is defined this way:

```
CREATE TABLE Logistics (
    country TEXT,
    Costs_Inbound CHAR(255),
    Costs_Storage CHAR(255),
    Costs_Outbound CHAR(255)
);
```

To query the Costs_Outbound I use the following SQL:

```
SELECT country,
FORMAT(sum(Costs_Outbound), 2 ,'DE_DE') Costs_Outbound
FROM Logistics
GROUP BY country WITH ROLLUP
```

I use the `FORMAT` function with `DE_DE` to change the thousand seperators from `","` to `"."` and the decimal places from `"."` to `","`.

All this works fine so far.

---

However, now I want that instead of only 2 decimal places **infinite decimal places** are displayed so I changed the query to:

```
SELECT country,
FORMAT(sum(Costs_Outbound),'DE_DE') Costs_Outbound
FROM Logistics
GROUP BY country WITH ROLLUP
```

However, now it does not show any decimal places at all and the `DE_DE` format is also gone.

Do you have any idea to solve this issue?

Comment: What is "Infinite decimal places" in computer terms, given that floating point numbers are determined by IEEE 754 (and have 15 significant figures in 8 bytes) and decimals are fixed point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't specify number of decimal places to round the value to, it takes the default `0` which means no decimal places at all. I don't think you need infinite number as you've mentioned just because you can have **3** decimal places maximum as per your definition `Costs_Outbound DECIMAL(65,3)`.

That said 3 seems like a number you're looking for.

```
SELECT country,
FORMAT(sum(Costs_Outbound), 3 ,'DE_DE') Costs_Outbound
FROM Logistics
GROUP BY country WITH ROLLUP
```

If you need more (for example 255), you should consider altering your column data type and putting the same number into [`FORMAT(X, D, [locale])`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_format) as `D` argument - see below. Also, to get rid of trailing zeros you could use [`TRIM`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim):

```
TRIM(TRAILING '0' FROM FORMAT(sum(Costs_Outbound), 255 ,'DE_DE')) Costs_Outbound
```

Comment: Hi Kami G., that was mistake in my question. Sorry about it. I changed the DECIMAL (65,3) to CHAR(255) now to emphasize that there should not be a limit to the 3 decimal places.

Comment: You could apply second part of my answer and include 255 as the argument.

Comment: You mean changing the D to 255?

Comment: Exactly, so the place where you had put "2" as decimal places, put the maximum number of characters that your column can hold.

Comment: Looks good. Do you also have an idea how I could get rid of all the 0 that come to fill up the decimal places?

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot. I also updated everything here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/28c574/11

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr There's no such entity as *infinite decimal places* in computer arithmetic.

The definition of `Costs_Outbound` in your table has three decimal places. Therefore, if your arithmetic (sums and so forth) is all addition and subtraction, your results will always have three decimal places.

If you perform multiplication or division, the result potentially has more significant digits to the right of the decimal point. ( 60.000 / 3.000 = 6.66666... ).
  Still, the data type you chose `DECIMAL(65,3)` is limited to three decimal places. Arithmetic results on those numbers are rounded correctly to three decimals. The result above in your data type is 6.667.

You could use `DOUBLE`, which employs [64-bit IEEE 748 floating point numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format). That data type gives you roughly 15 significant decimal digits and allows the decimal point to appear anywhere in the value. Physicists and engineers generally use these numbers. But `DOUBLE` and `FLOAT` data types are approximations of physical measurements. So, when displayed with all their precision sometims surprising  results appear: you might get `123.45000000001` where you expected `123.45000000000`.

It's possible you can try using a larger fractional part in your column definition. For example, `DECIMAL(63,6)` might help.